# Variable inside a function?

Tags: jquery, css

I might be going about this in the wrong way but I am trying to get a function to work on multiple divs through a var. Its just a close button that will slideUp the div and fadeIn other divs.

```
$(function () {
var pages = '#strategic-staffing', '#structured-cabling', '#security-solutions';
$('.close-button').click(function (event) {
    $(pages).slideUp('fast');
    $('#one-third, #one-third-last').fadeIn();
   });
});
```

Comment: The `var pages = ...` line should only have two `'`s. One at the start, and one at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `pages` should be like this

```
var pages = '#strategic-staffing, #structured-cabling, #security-solutions';
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry I am missed that. I think my brain is fried from being up all night.